# Is it better to create lots of Dictionaries or a single combined Dictionary to hold counter variables?

Tags: c#

For example, I can create a dictionary to hold each counter variable category separately:

```
private Dictionary<Int32, Int32> CountersA = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
private Dictionary<Int32, Int32> CountersB = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
private Dictionary<Int32, Int32> CountersC = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
```

The dictionary Key will be common across all dictionaries and the number of entries will change at run-time, because this is for a muti-touch application and the number of keys generated will be the number of fingers touching.

The counter for each dictionary entry will be rapidly added to and reset in real-time at run-time (i.e. when fingers are moving across a surface).  Any given Key will always appear in each dictionary, the Value for that key in each dictionary will be used for a different purpose.

Would it be better to create, for example, a Struct that holds all the Values for any given Key and so just a single dictionary consisting of the Key and a Struct, or would there be adverse performance affects from continually reading and writing the Struct values?  Or is there simply a better way of doing this, bearing in mind that speed performance is the issue here?

Comment: Do you have to deal with any concurrency issues?

Comment: Do you have an upper limit on the number of possible fingers? (E.g. imposed by your hardware?) If so, it'll be more performant to use arrays rather than dictionaries.

Comment: @Nate Kohl: I cannot see any place where there would be a concurrency issue.

Comment: @Rawling:  I believe (off the top of my head) the limit is 4 (this is a Windows Phone 7 context).

Comment: In that case, three `int[4]` arrays should be much more performant than the dictionaries, and won't waste too much space while fewer than four fingers are used.

Comment: @Rawling It won't waste any space. An array of 4 objects uses 24-28 bytes on x86. A `Dictionary` with 1 object uses 124-132 bytes. (Note that this difference is most apparent with so few items in the dictionary due to a bit of fixed overhead in `Dictionary`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have as keys only the number of fingers touching (say 10 ;-) you need to skip the dictionaries and indeed create an array of the struct that contains your data.

```
var FingerData = new myStruct[maxFingers];
```

This way you will point directly to the data (dictionaries are O(1) but need to calculate the bucket from your key). It will also be a smaller datastructure so it will better fit into caches and cpu registers and might thus be a little faster.